# Overlay menu falling behind header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have an issue with my header where it appears in front of my overlay menu which appears when the hamburger is clicked. I tried applying a higher z-index, but that didn't work.

Any advice would be brilliant.

http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/ZBEEyM

```js
/*!
 * classie v1.0.0
 * class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * MIT license
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true, unused: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );

( function () {

    var $navUL = $( 'nav ul' );

    $( '.hamburger-menu' ).on( 'click', function () {

        $( this ).toggleClass( 'show' );
        $navUL.toggleClass( 'hidden' );

    } );

} )();

function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";

$bar-width: 50px;
$bar-height: 4px;
$bar-spacing: 15px;

body {
 background: #000000;
  font-family: Teko;
  color: #ffffff;
}

header .hamburger-menu {
 position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 45px;
  left: 45px;
  margin: auto;
  width: $bar-width;
 height: $bar-height + $bar-spacing*2;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
    margin-left: 60px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.show .text {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX( -10px );
}


.bar,
.bar:after,
.bar:before {
  width: $bar-width;
 height: $bar-height;
}

.bar {
 position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
 transform: translateY($bar-spacing);
 background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
 transition: all 0ms 300ms;
  
  .show & {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
  }
}

.bar:before {
 content: "";
 position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
 left: 0;
 bottom: $bar-spacing;
 background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
 transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.bar:after {
 content: "";
 position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
 left: 0;
 top: $bar-spacing;
 background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
 transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.show .bar:after {
 top: 0;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
}

.show .bar:before {
 bottom: 0;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1em;
  border-color: black;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #bc31fe;
}
nav ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Teko;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  
  &.hidden {
    display: none;
  }
    
    a {
    @include transition-duration(0.5s);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}

.overlay .contacts {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 37px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .01em;
    z-index: 2;
}
.contacts {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #10131a;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

.bigtext {
  font-size: 50em;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #0683c9;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}
header h1#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    float: center;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
header nav a {
    line-height: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #9fdbfc;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}
header.smaller {
    height: 110px;
}
header.smaller h1#logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
header.smaller nav a {
    line-height: 75px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
    header h1#logo {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    header nav {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    header nav a {
        line-height: 50px;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    header.smaller {
        height: 75px;
    }
    header.smaller h1#logo {
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    header.smaller nav {
        height: 35px;
    }
    header.smaller nav a {
        line-height: 35px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko" rel="stylesheet"> 

<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            LOGO
        </h1>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="text">MENU</div>
 </div>
    </div>
</header><!-- /header -->

 <nav>
  <ul role="navigation" class="overlay hidden">
   <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">RESUME</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

<div class="contacts">
      <address>someperson@somewhere.com</address>
</div>

<div class="bigtext">THIS IS PLACEHOLDER</div>
```

Comment: try changing the `z-index` of `.hamburger-menu` to a higher valuethan your header

Comment: It is not the issue with the hamburger, but the purple box that appears when you click on the hamburger. It is under the blue header which is the issue. Adding a z-index to the overlay isn't working.

Comment: if you change the z-index of the `.overlay` to 999 it comes on top of the header if that is what you meant

Comment: But then the hamburger menu is hidden behind the overlay and it becomes impossible to close it.

Comment: you could add an close option to the overlay instead of showing the hamburgermenu in the overlay

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding some margin to the overlay area:

```
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){

        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
          $('.overlay').css('marginTop',110);
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
              $('.overlay').css('marginTop',150);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENxoOg

Comment: Sorry that is not exactly what I meant, the overlay is the big purple box that appears when you click on the hamburger. Currently the blue header bar lays over the purple box.

Comment: Is there a way to have the purple box overlay appear over the header? The original concept was something similar to the overlay menu on https://bert.house/en/

Comment: yes it is, you will need to modify your code so the header doesn't stay fixed and be a part of the overlay

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
header.smaller h1#logo {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

see demo here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWNYZP

Comment: The overlay that I mean is the big purple box that appears when you click on the hamburger. Currently the blue header bar lays over the purple box.